# What does the type { [key: string]: boolean; } mean?

Tags: typescript

Run into such thing lately, a function declaration:

```ts
static required(control: AbstractControl): {
  [key: string]: boolean;
};
```

What is this return value? An object with an arbitrary amount of properties, where each of them is a boolean and has a name, which appears to be a string? It's more of a typescript question I guess, but just in case someone wonders where I found that - it's Angular's `Validators` class.

Comment: Here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: It might be better idea to abandon now `{[key: K]: T}` construction but use JavaScript built-in [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-key-string-string

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This is a key/value structure, named [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)  (or previously known as [indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)) in typescript.

The key is a `string` and the value is a `boolean`. For example:

```
let map : { [key: string]: boolean} = {};
map["foo"] = true;
map["bar"] = false;
map.foo = true;
map["foobar"] = "foo"; // Throws exception
map[1] = true; // Curiously doesn't throws exception
```

Check [this sample on the Typescript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20map%20%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20boolean%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Amap%5B%22foo%22%5D%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0Amap%5B%22bar%22%5D%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0Amap%5B%22foobar%22%5D%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20Throws%20exception%0D%0Amap%5B1%5D%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20Curiously%20doesn%27t%20throws%20exception%0D%0Amap.foo%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20Throws%20exception)

Comment: Why `map.foo = true; // Throws exception`??

Comment: @lonewarrior556 The code "map.foo = true" actually doesn't throw an exception. The original answer claimed that it did, but that was incorrect, and the answer has been [udated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43396767/revisions) accordingly. The TypeScript Playground link, however, still includes the erroneous comment.

Comment: Ran into a similar bit of code, where one of the logic branches returns null, but the return type is  {[key: string]: boolean}  and it tells me null is not assignable to this type.  Maybe I have strict null type checking on and hte sample doesn't?  I don't know what to make my return type so it works.

Answer (score 0):

This structure can also be written in terms of the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) utility type (introduced in TypeScript 2.1).

> `Record<Keys, Type>` 
> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

The type `{[key: string]: boolean;}` is equivalent to `Record<string, boolean>`.