# Props not being checked when using styled components with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to implement a custom component which can be used with `styled-components`. The problem is that when using styled-components with typescript, the resulting styled-component does not seem to be providing correct type checking for the props it accepts. For instance, Suppose the following is my component:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<{identifier: string, option?: 'a' | 'b'}> {
    render() {
         const {identifier, ...props} = this.props;
         return <h1 {...props}>{identifier}</h1>
    }
}
```

And I am trying to wrap it with styled-components as

```
const WrappedComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
    border: 1px solid
`
```

Now when I am trying to render the `WrappedComponent` as

```
....
render() {
    return <WrappedComponent identifier="abc" />
}
```

Typescript throws an error along the lines of:

```
Type '{ identifier: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<{}, never> & Partial<Pick<{}, never>>, never> & { theme?: any; } & { as?: "symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | ... 165 more ... | undefined; }'.
Property 'identifier' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<{}, never> & Partial<Pick<{}, never>>, never> & { theme?: any; } & { as?: "symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | ... 165 more ... | undefined; }'
```

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

Everything seems to be working correctly if I change `option?: 'a' | 'b'` to `option?: string`

typescript version: 3.2.2
styled-components version: 4.1.3
@types/styled-components version: 4.1.4
react version: 16.6.3
@types/react version: 16.7.17

Comment: Cannot reproduce it locally, even with the same versions provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `[key: string]: string` so according to that `invalidProp` is a valid prop of type string and also has a valid string value. If props are pre-defined then you can create an interface all those. Here is another relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396522/what-does-the-type-key-string-boolean-mean) which can help you.

```
export interface IProps {
   name: string;
   validProp: string;
   anotherValidProp: string;
}
```

Also not related to this particular error but `myComponent` should be `MyComponent`.