# What is the correct TypeScript interface for an object with one or more properties of the same type?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm learning TypeScript and I recently wrote a small demo React app that processes user feedback data about pasta favourites.  The app reads in JSON data and filters it to extract, for each user, the data I'm interested in.  Which in this case are the user's name, their gender, and their favourite pastas, which are stored in an object whose keys are the pasta names (for example, 'spaghetti') and whose values are numbers.

These are the interfaces I came up with, which work

```
export interface PastaData {
    [key: string]: number | undefined,
}

export interface UserData {
    name: string,
    gender:String,
    favorites: PastaData
}
```

and my user data would thus be an array of UserData

```
UserData[]
```

My question is why the first interface, for 'PastaData' works correctly.  In my case, a user object will be something like

```
{
name: 'Frank Frankson',
gender: 'male',
favorites: {
            'spaghetti':99.242342,
            'fusilli':42.5234234,
            'linguine':84.523422,
            'ravioli':92.234234
           }
}
```

Why, then, does it work to have only *one*

```
[key: string]: number | undefined,
```

when there are multiple instances of that type in the real object?  How does TypeScript type check the object -- does it read in the JSON data at 'compile' time and then check that against the interface?  Does it only check one entry, that is the one for 'spaghetti' and see that that fits and then ignore the rest?

And why the `| undefined`?  Because the interface somehow reads all the possible pasta types and when some don't appear in an actual data object, it has to say that for *those* pasta type keys (those that don't appear in the object) the *value* is `undefined` ?

Thanks for any insights!  As said, through my own research and with the help of Stack Overflow, it all works fine, but I want to increase my *understanding* of what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the type { \[key: string\]: boolean; } mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396522/what-does-the-type-key-string-boolean-mean)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: @wvteijlingen, Indeed, it would seem to be explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types.  Still, I'd be keen to understand why the `| undefined` is necessary -- that is, TypeScript does a 'compile time' pass through all the data that might be imported to use that type and the indexed type must support all possible keys, some of which return `undefined` ?  What if the data were read in through an API call, how does it know that an `| undefined` is necessary?

Comment: Who says that having `undefined` there is necessary? Typescript does not do do any checking at run time. From the json you've provided, it does not seem necessary to have `undefined` there.

Comment: ```[key: string]: number | undefined``` means the instance of the interface should have all its properties' name, for example ```'spaghetti'```, are type of string and the corresponding value should be number or undefined. I think typescript doesn't check the real type during runtime.

Comment: @Philipl -- Thanks.  What's confusing me is the _need_ for the `undefined`.  When I didn't have `undefined` TypeScript balked because each data object would only contain a subset of pasta names, and for those names that were _in the data_ but which didn't appear in that particular object, it would find `undefined`.  E.g., in the example above, it would find `undefined` for 'orecchiette', because it's not in this data object, but _does_ appear in the data for other data objects.

Comment: In this case, undefined is needed because there is a chance the property you use do not exist on the object.

Comment: @wvteijlingen.  You seem to be right -- I've removed the `| undefined` and TypeScript seems happy.  When I wrote the project some days ago (I'm reviewing it now), it did complain until I put it in.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that I am using an indexable type (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), whose use is demonstrated in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396522/what-does-the-type-key-string-boolean-mean) question.