# Are the types `{ [key in string]: boolean };` and `{ [key : string]: boolean };` equivalent?

Tags: typescript

In [react-select](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/74703a87eb03dc98918016fefb85a1592ab4afed/types/react-select/src/Select.d.ts#L53) I stumbled across the line

```js
export type SelectComponentsProps = { [key in string]: any };
```

I know from
[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)
that

```js
type Keys = 'option1' | 'option2';
type Flags = { [K in Keys]: boolean };
```

is equivalent to

```js
type Flags = {
    option1: boolean;
    option2: boolean;
}
```

I also know from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396522/what-does-the-type-key-string-boolean-mean)
that `{ [key: string]: boolean; };` will be satisfied by this:

```js
let map : { [key: string]: boolean} = {};
map["foo"] = true;
map["bar"] = false;
map["foobar"] = "foo"; // Throws exception
map[1] = true; // Curiously doesn't throws exception
map.foo = true; // Throws exception
```

So, is `{ [key in string]: boolean };` equivalent to `{ [key : string]: boolean };`?

If not, what does `{ [key in string]: boolean };` mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some differences can be observed indeed, as you showed, and as below

```js
type T1 = {[key: string]: null};
type T2 = {[key in string]: null};

const t1: T1 = {'foo': null, 10: null};
const t2: T2 = {'foo': null, 10: null};

type S1 = keyof T1; // string | number
type S2 = keyof T2; // string

const s1: S1 = 10;
const s2: S2 = 10; // error
```

<sub>[TS Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gbQNYRALigZ2ACcBLAOwHMBdPMgVwBsGBfAbgChRJYAmJVTNijkCxctVqMWHdgGMA9mUJRgcPPH4oA5ADN58rZKYAaKHAAMR6XMXLgPdX2Ta9Bq6YtW27TuGgBlBGQsEHkdWDhWKAB6aNFSSigAHyh6AFsAIwgiX25-JygQsN4o2PjxHwUlYAI1KED+Cw4q5XwHeoKmmLjsonkcoA)</sub>

Observe also that one syntax accepts optional keys but not the other:

```js
type T1 = {[key: string]: null};
type T2 = {[key in string]: null};

type T1opt = {[key: string]?: null}; // invalid syntax
type T2opt = {[key in string]?: null};
```

<sub>[TS Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gbQNYRALigZ2ACcBLAOwHMBdPMgVwBsGBfAbgChRJYAmJVTNijkCxctVqMWHTuGjwA9mGD90WXKNKUqAfklM2UAPRHhZAG4BDBiQAmBEGWCWAHrO4weSlcjVCRhFrUelD0BhxAA)</sub>

Finally, using `in` apparently allows for self-reference, as seen in [@types/styled-components/index.d.ts#24](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L24):

> `// This is "[key in string]" and not "[key: string]" to allow CSSObject to be self-referential`

Comment: Interestingly enough, quickinfo intellisense (hover over the type in an editor like VSCode or The Playground to see more info) shows `{[x in string]: X}` as `{[x: string]: X}`.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issues:  [Microsoft/TypeScript#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592), [Microsoft/TypeScript#31013](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31013)