# React Typescript - Handle Form Change for Object with Multiple Field

Tags: reactjs, types

I have a state called `newItem` with data type of `ItemModel`. This state have 4 field (name, sku, price, image). I tried to use handleFormChange function (usually use this function in React.js), but it give an error about `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ItemModel'` and `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ItemModel'`.

This is ItemModel :

```
export interface ItemModel {
   name: string,
   price: number,
   sku: string,
   image: File
}
```

This is the state interface :

```
newItem: {
   name: "",
   sku: "",
   price: 0,
   image: new File([""], "")
 }
```

This is how I handle the form change

```
    handleFormChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        let tempItem = {...this.state.newItem};
        tempItem[event.target.id] = event.target.value; //error line
        this.setState({
            newItem: tempItem
         }, () => {
            console.log('value', this.state.newItem);
         })
    }
```

This is how I call the function from InputField

```
<TextField size="small" label="Name" id="name" onChange={this.handleFormChange}/>
```

I really appreciate your help for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add about `ItemModel`?

Comment: @zynkn sure! already add it

Comment: Could you add about `event.target`?

Comment: @zynkn it get the data from whatever input its called on. So `event.target.id` will get the id from each of the TextField

Comment: first, in your `ItemModel` there's nothing about `id`. That's why `this.state.newItem[event.target.id]` is error. 
second, `this.state.newItem[event.target.id]` it not immutable.

Comment: @zynkn Didn't it get the value of id for each input? if i put some input it TextField with id value "name", then it will become like this `this.state.newItem[name]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, insert `[key: string]: string | number | File` to the ItemModel fix the problem. For more information [What does the type { [key: string]: boolean; } mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396522/what-does-the-type-key-string-boolean-mean)